# Create a circle behind inline elements that sit between the text and the background

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have the following HTML (redundant stuff removed for clarity):

```html
<div style="background-color: red;">
    <div style="
        padding: 4% 15%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        color: #fff;
    ">
        <h1 style="
            font-weight: 400;
        ">This text should be normal, <b>this</b> this should have a circle behind it.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS

```css
b {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 800;
}
b:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background: #8866c5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 130%;
    padding-top: 130%;
    left: -15%;
    transform: translateY(-65%);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The objective is to create a pseudo element that forms a circle (a 'spotlight') behind the `<b>` elements (and obviously also behind the rest of the text). This works, but as soon as I place it in a container with a background (like I've done here in the container that has the red background), the pseudo element falls behind the background. How can I fix this?

Comment: you can use `isolation: isolate;`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was very simple. You have to add `z-index: 0` to the element carrying the background (in this case the div with the red background). I always thought `z-index` only made sense on non static-positioned elements.

Comment: This will only work if that div with red background has a position value other than `static` (which is the default value if you did not set its position)

Comment: No, that's not true. Just tried it in Firefox and Chrome by setting the background DIV to static explicitely

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code in the answer? I am pretty curious why it works. I've tested in my side and z-index won't work on non-positioned elements. Though I think @temani-afif's comment is a better choice.

Comment: Unless its under a grid or flex container?

Comment: @SyndRain the working code is basically the code from the original question, save the `z-index: 0;`, It doesn't seem to do anything to the element itself, but create a hierarchy that other elements can position itself in.

Comment: Yes you are correct, they call it stacking context! It's just that `z-index:0` should only create a stacking context when the element position is not `static`.

Comment: Here's a [list given by mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context), you can see the rules that when could `z-index` creates stacking contexts. When `z-index` has value other than `auto`, the stacking context is created when the element is either: 1. positioned, 2. child of a `flex` container, or 3. child of a `grid` container

Comment: @SyndRain I know, that's what I always learned and thought. But still this does the trick. Maybe something I'm overlooking, missing, or some glitch in the spec.